# Algebra Question on $\theta + \frac{1}{\theta} = \frac{\theta}{1+ \theta^2}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Answer for one of my tutorial question was $$\theta + \dfrac{1}{\theta} = \dfrac{\theta}{1+ \theta^2}.$$ But, I quite confuse because shouldn't it be like $$\theta + \dfrac{1}{\theta} = \dfrac{\theta^2 + 1}{\theta}.$$ 
How come it got $\dfrac{\theta}{1+ \theta^2}$?

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: I think you're being asked to find the finitely many values of $\theta$ for which it's true, rather than proving that all $\theta$ work.

Comment: Is it an equation to solve or an identity?

Comment: It's pretty clear the asker is asking, knowing $$\theta + \frac 1\theta = \frac{\theta^2}\theta + \frac 1\theta = \frac {\theta^2 + 1}{\theta}$$why, after looking at a solution it says the the right hand side should be $\frac{\theta}{1 + \theta^2}$.  Your own solution is correct.  The one you're comparing it to is incorrect.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct

$$ θ+(1/θ)=(θ^2+1)/θ \neq θ/(1+θ^2) $$

Sometimes misprints happen is books or notes.